# Spontaneous and Favoured Chemical Reactions

Tags: equilibrium

I have some problems in understanding what is the difference between a reaction which is spontaneous and a reaction which is termodynamically favoured. I'm looking at the equation of Gibbs Free Energy:
$$\Delta G = \Delta G^0 + RT ln \prod a_i^{\nu_i}$$
I know that a reaction is spontaneous if $\Delta G <0$ and a reaction is Termodynamically favoured at a given T, by convenction, if $\Delta G^0<0$.
So the condition of $\Delta G^0<0$ is a necessary, but not sufficient condition to be spontaneous? 
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You are missing a ln before the product.

Comment: Your equation shows in what direction an equillibrium  reaction will move to achieve td. equillibrium. A "spontaneous" reaction must of course be thermodynamically possible, but it also requires a viable kinetic pathway, which cannot be predicted from such simple thermodynamics.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply!  Therefore a reaction which is thermodynamically unfavoured in the considered direction will have a small amount of products with respect to the reactants but it will occur anyway. The condition of unfavoured reaction can be overcome with kinetics considerations (i.e. catalyzers)?